# Reshape data to match statsmodels and exog contains inf or nans

Tags: python, pandas, panel, statsmodels, panel-data

I'm attempting to set up a panel TVPVAR using statsmodels, running first a local model.

Coming from Stata, I am confused on how to proper reshape my data to match what statsmodels expects.

The data are saved in long format file in the way the image here shows.

[Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLjCC.png)

There are an identifier (id ), year, country and then a set of thirty (30) variables, say variable1 to variable30 for each country and year. A typical long panel data format.

I am getting an error

```
An unsupported index was provided and will be ignored when e.g. forecasting. self._init_dates(dates, freq)
```

So, my first question is how to properly reshape my data
in order to be compatible with statsmodels for a local and a tvpvar model ?

Also, the second error I get is when I run the tvpvar model is:

```
exog contains inf or nans
```

In my Var model, all my variables are endogenous. I do have gaps in the data, of course. How is that solved? Could just setting `exog=None` be a solution?
Since I do not know how to share, paste data in the forum, apart from the screenshot above, a small sample of my data are in the following link [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YmKseNKEGZTQk_II4fOwgUVfZLAgVqJT/view?usp=share_link](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I set up the panel framework as follows:

```
%matplotlib inline

from importlib import reload
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import invwishart, invgamma

#1 

import pyreadstat

dtafile = 'panel.dta'
dta, meta = pyreadstat.read_dta(dtafile)
dta.tail() 

labels=list(meta.column_labels)   
column=list(meta.column_names)

   
#  Panel data settings 
year = dta.year
year = pd.Categorical(dta.year)
dta = dta.set_index([ "country", "year"])
dta["year"] = year


dta.head()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Both versions are explained in the docs: [local level model](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_tvpvar_mcmc_cfa.html#Local-level-model) and [TVP-VAR](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_tvpvar_mcmc_cfa.html#Application:-Bayesian-analysis-of-a-TVP-VAR-model-by-MCMC). If your question is how you can reshape your data to match what statsmodels expects, please setup sample data that reflects your raw data (I will not download anything from someone's google drive).

Comment: I have edited my question. I have now provided a screenshot. 
 My question is how to reshape data to match stats models and how to solve exog contains inf or nans . 
Thank you for your help in advanced.